# Azure Logic Apps - Connection to Azure SQL Server "Bad Gateway" Error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I'm using a logic app to pull tweets from the native Twitter connector, score the sentiment of the tweet, and then store the result in a table within an Azure SQL Server database. The first two steps work fine, but setting up the connection to the SQL Server is giving me trouble. When I set up the connection, I give it a name and then select the database I want from the available ones shown in my Azure subscription, then provide the username and password. After hitting create it asks for a table name - I click the dropdown and it says "Loading" for a while, then shows this:

[image: Bad Gateway]

"Could not retrieve values. BadGateway"

I can't seem to find any details on this error message in the Microsoft docs, is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Make sure you use the GetRows action on the SQL Server connector.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo is there a reason for that? I'm just trying to insert data, not read anything. I also tried to add that action into my app and get the same error when selecting a table.

Comment: Does the login used to connect to the database has permissions over the selected table?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo yes, I have given the user access to the datareader and datawriter roles at the database level - I also ensured the user has access to the schema as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database server is allowing access to azure services in the firewall.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Comment: thanks for the reply - I have Azure connections turned on at the server level (added 0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0 just to be sure and it told me to use the config instead, which is flipped on).